# Objective C Access Tools and Buttons in sub UIVIEW

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

i made an UIview as a subview to be as a top slid menu bar when touch button it will slide down and it is work fine but the problem is when it down i can not access any tools or buttons in it

in the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainGameVC : UIViewController
{
    //IBOutlet UIView *TopMenuViewer;

    int Menu;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *TopMenuViewer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TestText;


-(IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender;

@end
```

in the .m file

```
#import "MainGameVC.h"

@interface MainGameVC ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TextBox;


@end

@implementation MainGameVC


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

    }
    return self;
}

-(IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender{

    if (Menu == 0) {
        Menu = 1;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        self.TopMenuViewer.Frame = CGRectMake(0, -100, 0, 0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.TopMenuViewer];
        [self.TopMenuViewer accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused];


    }else{
        Menu = 0;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        self.TopMenuViewer.Frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.TopMenuViewer];
        [self.TopMenuViewer accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused];
        [self.TopMenuViewer accessibilityElements];
        }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Menu = 0;
    self.TopMenuViewer.Frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    [


}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/



@end
```

Comment: Try to set `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` in your `UIView` animation.

Comment: how i can set this option to my UIView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should use UIScrollView instead of UIView

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that `AllowUserInteraction` will solve your issue. This is approach to set options for the animation:

```
-(IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender{

    if (Menu == 0) {
        Menu = 1;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 
                          delay:0.0         
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction |
                        UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut)
                     animations:^
                             {
                              self.TopMenuViewer.Frame = CGRectMake(0, -100, 0, 0);
                             }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                              [self.TopMenuViewer accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused];
                             }];
```

Consider attaching the project to the question for us to have a look.

Comment: still same problem, i add a textbox for testing once the uiview slide down can not access anything inside it, actually what i am trying to do is something like all heyday side slide menu when user touch a button this menu will slide down and can access all elements inside it so it is work fine and it is slide down but can not access any elements inside id once it is slide down

Comment: i already solve the problem should not use UIView, should be UIScrollView, this allow me to access all elements

Comment: great! you should post the answer for reference.